# HTML data property with multiple values, filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of divs on a page.  I have a filter system that fills in a 'data-' element with a possible list of values.

Example:

```
  <div data-myvalues="value1,value2,value3"></div>
 <div data-myvalues="value2,value3"></div>
 <div data-myvalues="value1,value2"></div>
 <div data-myvalues="value1,value3"></div>
```

Then I have some jQuery that tries to filter based on some selections that include the values in the data-myvalues attribute. However, the jQuery filter does not quite work because I think it sees the values as including the comma (,) in the value.
How, in jQuery, would I filter based on an if the divs include the values or not. I am currently using the jQuery

```
 $("div[data-myvalue*='value1']").show();
```

But it seems to now quite work for some reason it will work if the data-myvalues only has one value in it, the jQuery works, but if there are multiples separated by a comma, the jQuery does not work.

I have a JS fiddle here with a simple sample code I was messing with to get the proof of concept to work. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ebz3cmjn/1/

Is there a better way to list values on an element then filter them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me it is not clear the output you want...

Comment: In the JS Fiddle. I would like anything with the data attribute value that contains "nationman"  to be colored yellow.  But currently the jQuery only seems to work if the data value only has one value in it not multiples separated by a comma

Comment: So the in fiddle you want only the second and third input to be yellow?

Comment: Please check out my answer....

Answer (score 2):

The `data` attribute takes JSON object which you can take advantage of.

Given the following element:

```
<input data-nations='["anothernation", "nationman", "country"]' type="text" value="Germany">
```

You could filter the desired elements based on the target value:

```
var targetNation = "nationman";

$("input[data-nations]")
  .filter(function () {
    // Returns the list as array
    return $(this).data("nations").indexOf(targetNation) > -1;
  })
  .css("background-color", "blue");
```

Note the two differences between the quotes:

```
// will parse correctly
data-nations='["anothernation", "nationman", "country"]'

// will NOT parse correctly since it will be treated as plain text
data-nations="['anothernation', 'nationman', 'country']"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('div'), function(i, v){
       var values = $(v).data('myvalues');
       if(values.indexOf('value1') != -1) {
         $(v).show();
        } else {
          $(v).hide();
       }
     })
  });
```

And html content with data values:

```
<div data-myvalues="value1,value2,value3"></div>
<div data-myvalues="value2,value3"></div>
<div data-myvalues="value1,value2"></div>
<div data-myvalues="value1,value3"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `.not()` like the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[data-me*='nationman']").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $("input").not("[data-me*='nationman']").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-me="nationality" type="text" value="Chinese">
<input data-me="nationman" type="text" value="English">
<!--This doesn't work with more than one value-->
<input data-me="nationman,country" type="text" value="Germany">
<input data-me="anothernation" type="text" value="Norwegian">

<p>This selector selects all input fields with the attribute name that contains the string 'nation'.</p>
```

You can also loop through all elements with `.each()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-myvalues]').each(function(){
     var values = $(this).data('myvalues');
     if(values.includes('value1'))
      $(this).show();
     else
      $(this).hide();
   })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-myvalues="value1,value2,value3">value1,value2,value3</div>
<div data-myvalues="value2,value3">value2,value3</div>
<div data-myvalues="value1,value2">value1,value2</div>
<div data-myvalues="value1,value3">value1,value3</div>
```

Comment: Its partially correct. As per snippet `String.includes()` is getting used it will evealuate to true for `value1` event if values are like `data-myvalues="value12,value3"`,    I would recommend to use proper JSON format in `data-*` attribute  i.e. `<div data-myvalues='["value1","value2","value3"]'>value1,value2,value3</div>` then the `data('myvalues')` will convert it to `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the snippet;
I have modified you code a litte bit, hope this will help to get your answer;
This is a little bit tricky answer, but you can easily understand the code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var el = $('input');
 el.each(item =>{
  var attr = el[item].dataset
  if(attr.me.match(/nationman/)){
  el[item].setAttribute('style', 'background-color:yellow')
 }else{
  el[item].setAttribute('style', 'background-color:red')
 }
})
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input data-me="nationality" type="text" value="Chinese">
<input data-me="nationman" type="text" value="English">
<!--This doesn't work with more than one value-->
<input data-me="nationman, country" type="text" value="Germany">
<input data-me="anothernation" type="text" value="Norwegian">

<p>This selector selects all input fields with the attribute name that contains the string 'nation'.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This I think it will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[data-me*='nationman']").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $("input").not("[data-me*='nationman']").css("background-color", "red");
});
```